# How to monitor file transfer(upload/download) speed of a file in vsftpd

Tags: linux, vsftpd, file-transfer

I'm using **`vsftpd` as the server** in my Linux system. In other Linux system, I'm using **`curl` as a client** for uploading and downloading files.

I am able to monitor the current file transfer rate **at the client-side (`curl`)** with no issue.

```
curl --user root:root -o mydownloadefile ftp://192.168.7.5:/root/Videos/12_14_00.avi

curl -T upload_file_name ftp://192.168.5.3:2121/
```

Now on the `vsftpd` server side I can see detailed list of the transferred file using

```
tail -f /var/log/vsftpd.log
```

But I would also like to monitor the transferred file with the completed percentage **in real-time on the server side**. Is there a way to achieve this

Thanks for your time.